# Can't run installer from virtual folder in Oracle

Tags: virtual-machine, inno-setup

I have an interesting issue trying to install using Oracle Virtual Machine:

[image: Installer]

If I copy the file onto the C drive of the virtual box it installs. But from the mapped virtual folder it won't.

I tried running from command line with `/log=log.txt` and it won't get that far.

Comment: Did you try to use a full path to a log file on a C: drive?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That made no difference.

Comment: Try to debug it with Process Monitor: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That won't run either, not from the virtual shared drive anyway (which does have full access).

Comment: So put the procmon on a C drive.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I copied to C. Ran it. Hard to understand. Interesting it would not let me copy from E to C root. Had to copy to user folder.